# A question in linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix with real coefficients. If $A^n=I$ for some integer $n\ge3$, prove that $A^2=I$

I have no idea in proving this question, hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Hint 1: What are the eigenvalues of $A$?
Hint 2: What are the possible minimal polynomial's of $A$?

Comment: @AndrewD I can get one eigenvalue of $A^n$ is 1, but I don't know the connection with $A$

Comment: Starting point is the spectral theorem: A real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, and eigenvalues are real.

Comment: Take a step back, and think that if $(\lambda,x)$ is an eigenvalue/vector pair of $A$, what can we say about $A^n$?

Comment: @AndrewD Oh, I see. $A$ has an eigenvalue $1$. And I know how to prove that. Thank you

Comment: @user236626 Eigenvalue can also be $-1$.